# 4 bytes big-endian to int

Tags: php, preg-replace, pack, unpack

I have a file that contains data (keywords) to interpret and starts with 4-bytes big endian to determine number of keywords. I can't seem to get the proper integer value from it.

```
$bytes = "00000103";
$keywords = preg_replace("/(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})/u", "\x$1\x$2\x$3\x$4", $bytes);
var_dump($keywords);
$unpacked = unpack("N", $keywords);
var_dump($unpacked);
```

Outputs (incorrect):

```
string(16) "\x00\x00\x01\x03"
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(1551380528)
}
```

For testing purposes, I change the $keywords variable to:

```
$bytes = "\x00\x00\x01\x03";
```

It outputs (correct):

```
string(4) ""
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(259)
}
```

How do I change the data-type of $keywords? Searched a lot, but can't get it to work unfortunately.

PS. After posting, it doesn't show the 2 characters (boxes with questionmarks) in them in the correct output for string(4).

Comment: To change a datatype you can just cast it, like with anything `(int)` `(string)` etc.. but is the datatype your issue here?

Comment: Maybe my explanation if off. However, both $keywords output to a string, whereas the first one (incorrect) has 16 characters as opposed to the second (correct) one, that has 2 characters.

Comment: No the explanation is fine, but I'm using `gettype()` on both values and they're the same but for some reason, strict compare throws false against them both which tells me this could be an encoding issue with `preg_*` functions so I'm just googling around now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [hexdec-function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php):

```
$bytes = "00000103";
$dec = hexdec($bytes);
var_dump($dec);  //int(259)
```

Comment: I still wonder why the OP doesn't actually work. Perhaps it is a bug in PHP

Comment: It's not a bug. Strings like "\x00\x00\x01\x03" are interpreted by the PHP parser. This does not work if such an expression is generated dynamically by PHP.

Comment: I can see that, but where is this documented? I can't find it documented anywhere, not in the [strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) nor any of the documentation on hex. If it isn't documented, you're only assuming it is intentional. +1 for the work around though.

Comment: @Jaquarh: On PHP Doc "strings" it should have the most of it: 1.) that strings are binary in PHP and 2.) the escape sequences for double-quoted (`"`) strings. And last but not least: 3.) how dollar signs (`$`) are interpreted in double-quoted strings. Specifically for the last one, the study of the preg_replace PHP Doc page should uncover the insight on how to properly encode the replacement string.

Comment: I mean, not much of that makes sense because then why wouldn't `unpack("N", "{$keywords}")` work? Maybe I just don't understand what 'strings are binary' really equivalates too . Either way, interesting how it treats variables differently. @hakre

Comment: Because preg_replace is used wrong here.  This _should_ reveal what conceptually is wrong in asking the question that way, it's just sloppy code dumped on Stackoverflow without any properly minimized test-case which would have revealed it. E.g. when dealing with byte-sequences, only var_dump() output is normally not saying a lot b/c of printable characters, a hex-dump of strings gives more insights. But again, the code looks sloppy to me, so it's better to decipher it first in full before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Question remains thought, what you're seeing undocumented. `unpack("N", "{$keywords}")` you can expect to work, but you need to specify the input - `$keywords` is a variable and an example should be invariant on the input - also the expected output, the actual output and what blocks to explain the differences between the two.